# Does assertRaises (or assert_raises) exist in nose2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nose, nosetests

I am trying to write some nose tests  for a python project.  It has been a while (a year or so) since I last wrote some nostests and it looks like nose2 is the suggested module to use for this now.

I want to write a test to check that an exception is raised when the wrong value is sent into a def function. I know in nose is was used like this:

```
from nose.tools import assert_raises

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

assert_raises(TypeError, add, 2, "0")
```

I just can't find an equivalent use example for nose2, none of these imports work (there is a suggestion that nose2 is more like unittest than nose, which seems to use assertRaises):

```
from nose2 import assert_raises
from nose2 import assertRaises
from nose2.tools import assert_raises
from nose2.tools import assertRaises
```

A search of the nose2 documentation website has no mention of an assert_raises or assertRaises

Comment: I guess you're not using nose2 with unittest.TestCase subclasses? Else, you could just use unittest.TestCase.assertRaises() with nose2.

Comment: Since I raised this issue, and based on the answer below (more of a jumping off point) that is what I have gone back and done.  It is just not the way it was being done with the testing I was doing under nose.  I was hoping to get more feedback, but I am wondering if nose2 is ready for primetime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you can find it in `nose2.tools.such.helper`.  And no, I couldn't find it in the docs either.

Note there is both `Helper` and `helper`; the latter is just a singleton instance of the former.  Just to dispel any confusion, this is all they're doing under the hood:

```
class Helper(unittest.TestCase):

    def runTest(self):
        pass


helper = Helper()
```

i.e. it's just exposing the `unittest` assert* methods through a dummy `TestCase` instance.

Answer (score 0):

nose2.tools.such.helper is no longer available.

The proper solution is to know that in nose2, all test classes must inherit from `unittest.TestCase`, and therefore you switch to using [`self.assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)